# C# DirectoryInfo.GetFiles wildcard search

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

I am experiencing differences in behavior in the following code segment

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\");
FileInfo[] textFiles = di.GetFiles("log_???.???.txt");
```

Where ? is the wildcard for 0 or 1 characters, so this should return files in the path matching the patterns:

```
log_..txt
log_0.0.txt
log_00.00.txt
log_000.000.txt
```

All of these files are returned when compiled for Windows .NET framework 3.5 (desktop), but on the target embedded Windows CE 6 with .NET Compact Embedded Framework 3.5, I get no matches.

If I change the wildcard pattern from

```
FileInfo[] textFiles = di.GetFiles("log_???.???.txt");
```

to

```
FileInfo[] textFiles = di.GetFiles("log_*.*.txt");
```

Then I get all of the expected files in the pattern above.

Does anybody know why this is the case?
The files definitely exist on the target platform.

For reasons outside the scope of this question, I do strongly desire at least to understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I see a couple of issues.  I don't know if you left stuff out on purpose to keep the question simple, or if you missed these things, so I am listing all the problems I see:

1. You're not using verbatim string literals.  `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\");` doesn't compile because the '\' is interpreted as an escape character.  The same example with verbatim string literals is `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");` which does compile.
2. Windows CE/Mobile doesn't have a concept of drive letters.  `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");` on desktop is equivalent to `DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\");` on CE/Mobile.
3. This quote from you is incorrect:

   > ? is the wildcard for 0 or 1 characters

It's actually a wildcard for 1 character as mentioned [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.90).aspx)

> The asterisk (*) and question mark (?) are used as wildcard
>   characters, as they are in MS-DOS and Windows. The asterisk matches
>   any sequence of characters, **whereas the question mark matches any
>   single character**.

Comment: For points 1 and 2, I omitted the drive letter and literal string prefix for brevity as you suspected. For point 3, the directory info usage itself quotes ? Matching 0 or 1 characters. (See Nikunj link below). The link you mention references MSDOS. As I've said in my original question it detects 0-3 characters for the string of ??? Which contradicts your link. This implies the GetDirectoryInfo does not use the MSDOS strategy for .Net desktop, but maybe so for compact. At this point it seems like a lacking documentation issue specific to ?NET compact

Comment: For completeness sake, I tried in a DOS window creating three .txt files (0.txt, 00.txt and 000.txt). I then issued a "dir ???.txt command. All three files were returned. So, I don't know what the link you mention refers to the problem I am having.

Comment: That's great.  The fact is the Compact Framework 3.5 documentation refers to the ? wildcard as matching one character.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: *sigh* Good catch. Evidently after .NET Framework 3.5, the meaning for '?' changed from exactly one character (as you have pointed out all along) to 0 or 1 character. Thanks for being patient and for your help. If you edit your answer to include the link above I will then be able to edit it to give you proper credit.

Comment: The question has been updated.  This is quite a mess.  I've never heard of '?' matching one or more character on any platform, but clearly the Windows CMD.EXE currently does this.  How does it even make sense for both `*` and `?` to match one or more character?  Why have two different wildcards that mean the same thing?  (rhetorical, I know you didn't design this!) The bottom line is Windows CMD.EXE, MSDOS, .NET 4.5/4.6, are not the platform you're experiencing the problem with.  The platform you are experiencing the problem with is documented as '?' matching one character.

Comment: Agreed - don't know why '?' was ever implemented as only one character, but oh well. Thanks again!

Comment: The DotNet documentation here: < https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx > for DotNet 4.5 indicates that "?" is supposed to match "zero or one", but practical tests (using DotNet 4.5.1) indicate it still matches "exactly one".